# How do you identify an organic base?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, bond

**Problem:**

[image]

**Solution:**

The molecules with red crosses underneath them are considered organic bases.

**Question:**

From my understanding an organic base has an atom with a lone pair of electrons. Doesn't molecule (ii) have a lone pair of electrons and should thusly also be considered an organic base? If I am using the wrong method to identify organic bases, what other method should I use?

Comment: Nora, your understanding is correct. just remember that there are degrees of basicity. Amines are stronger bases than amides. An available electron pair makes a base, all that is needed is an appropriate acid. Check this for intra molecular acid base reactions with strange bases. https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/VirtTxtJml/rearrang.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organic bases are just organic compounds which act as bases. These primarily include amines.

**Compound two is an amide**. Amides are more acidic than amines, and they very rarely act as organic bases. They aren't classified as such.

The lone pair is not much available in an amide due to resonance, hence it acts as a base only when a strong acid is present. On the other hand, amide might act as an acid, donating proton. As $\ce{H+}$ comes out of the nitrogen in an amide, the negative charge is delocalized and hence the conjugate base is stabilized.

**PS.** This doesn't mean that an amide is much of an organic acid, either. They are both very weak bases *and* very weak acids.

Comment: You contradict yourself not a base! a very weak base!

Comment: @jimchmst By using the word *very weak* base I mean to say that it can't be treated as a base just like sodium hydroxide can't be treated as an acid. The words acid and base are often relative and interchangable in situations like these. Ethanol for example is more inclined towards the basic side and so it is a weak acid. It is just a matter of words.

Comment: If it is a matter of words lets use them correctly. There are degrees of basicity and it depends on the acid it is reacting with.  Add Al powder to a strong hydroxide solution to see how acidic it is. As for ethanol it definitely is an organic base but does not qualify under your answer or the tone of original question. Again you contradict yourself.

Comment: That is what I mean. The terms acid and bases are relative and depend on the reagent added.So I used the word very weak base instead of "not a base" at the end

Answer (score 2):

*Organic base has an atom with a lone pair of electrons*. This statement is not true considering the fact that the lone pair of the compound may be in resonance.

Consider the example of a carboxylic acid. They are organic bases under your definition as the oxygen has a lone pair. The second question is similar to a carboxylic acid.
Consider the image:[image]

The first situation shows amide acting as a base.This leads to a highly unstable structure.
The second situation shows amide behaving as an acid. This leads to a stable structure.
Hence as @TheFrightOfTheNight pointed out,the amides are acidic and so can't be called organic bases.